# MATLAB: How load a list of filenames from .txt file

Tags: string, matlab, import

**filelist.txt** contains a list of files:

```
/path/file1.json
/path/file2.json
/path/fileN.json
```

Is there a (simple) MATLAB command that will accept filelist.txt and read each file as a string and store each string into a cell array?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a simple command in MATLAB that reads a text file line by line. Did you search for one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `readtable`, asking it to read each line in full.

```
>> tbl = readtable('filelist.txt','ReadVariableNames',false,'Delimiter','\n');
>> tbl.Properties.VariableNames = {'filenames'}
tbl =
  3×1 table
        filenames     
    __________________
    '/path/file1.json'
    '/path/file2.json'
    '/path/fileN.json'
```

Then access the elements in a loop

```
for idx = 1:height(tbl)
   this_filename = tbl.filenames{idx};
end
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Good to avoid re-inventing the wheel

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a bit to specific for a standard function. However, it is easily doable with the combination of two functions:

First, you have to open the file:

```
fid = fopen('filelist.txt');
```

Next you can read line by line with:

```
line_ex = fgetl(fid)
```

This function includes a counter. If you call the function the next time, it will read the second line and so on. You find more information [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgets.html).

The whole code might look like this:

```
%   Open file
fid = fopen('testabc');

numberOfLines = 3;

%   Preallocate cell array
line = cell(numberOfLines, 1);

%   Read one line after the other and save it in a cell array
for i = 1:numberOfLines
    line{i} = fgetl(fid);
end

%   Close file
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this replace the for loop with a while loop:

```
i=0;
while ~feof(fid)
i=i+1
line{1} = fgetl(fid)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[Alternative to while loop: Retrieve the number of lines and use in Caduceus' for-loop:](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/81137-pre-determining-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file)

```
%   Open file
fid = fopen('testabc');

numberOfLines = numlinestextfile('testable');  % function defined below

%   Preallocate cell array
line = cell(numberOfLines, 1);

%   Read one line after the other and save it in a cell array
for i = 1:numberOfLines
    line{i} = fgetl(fid);
end

%   Close file
fclose(fid);
```

Custom function:

```
function [lineCount] = numlinestextfile(filename)
%numlinestextfile: returns line-count of filename
%   Detailed explanation goes here
if (~ispc) % Tested on OSX
  evalstring = ['wc -l ', filename];   
  % [status, cmdout]= system('wc -l filenameOfInterest.txt');
  [status, cmdout]= system(evalstring);
  if(status~=1)
      scanCell = textscan(cmdout,'%u %s');
      lineCount = scanCell{1}; 
  else
      fprintf(1,'Failed to find line count of %s\n',filenameOfInterest.txt);
      lineCount = -1;
  end
else

if (~ispc)     % For Windows-based systems
    [status, cmdout] = system(['find /c /v "" ', filename]);
    if(status~=1)
        scanCell = textscan(cmdout,'%s %s %u');
        lineCount = scanCell{3};
        disp(['Found ', num2str(lineCount), ' lines in the file']);
    else
        disp('Unable to determine number of lines in the file');
    end
end
end
```